# Showing dynamic sections with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, show

I'm trying to show a dynamic section with jQuery but I am getting problems.

My code is:

```
// Show data
${'#' + section + 'All'}.show();
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error: missing ; before statement
Line: 1905, Column: 5
```

Comment: Functions are called with parenthesis (`()`) not brackets. `$` is a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brackets are wrong, they shouldn't be curley, try

```
$('#' + section + 'All').show();
```

Comment: Thanks very much. For some reason I thought brackets were used.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
$('#' + section + 'All').show();
```

The brackets are used for jquery selectors, not braces {}.